# Laravel smlink not found

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, shared-hosting

I upload my laravel website to shared hosting ". Every things work except i am not able to retrieve images stored in the storage/public folder. I ran

```
 "php artisan storage:link"
```

but it says not found. I also tried

```
rm storage
```

but the getthe message **rm: cannot remove. Is directory**
[php artisan storage:link output from ssh command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E13QA.png)

Comment: This can be a number of things. Because you're using shared hosting, I would suspect a permissions issue. You can bypass this issue by linking your public storage to a public folder. That way you don't need to use a symlink.

Comment: I suspect its a permission issue as well. How could i link it?

Comment: `chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/project/`  give permission to storage

Comment: How did you "upload" your website? Have you checked whether the symlinks point to the proper directories? And how is this related to Composer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note,** I'm not addressing the original answer because it doesn't sound like it can be done. This is an alternate solution.

#### Solution

In your `config/filesystems.php` file, you'll see the following code (or something similar).

```
    'disks' => [

        'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app'),
        ],

        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],

        's3' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
            'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
            'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
            'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
            'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
            'endpoint' => env('AWS_ENDPOINT'),
        ],

    ],
```

To link your public disk to a public directory without using OS symlinks, change the `disks['public']['path']` to the public path of your choosing. For example,

```
    'disks' => [
        /** -- skipped code **/
        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => __DIR__ . '../public/images/`,
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/images',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],
        /** -- skipped code **/
    ],
```

#### Another Solution

You can totally use the S3 storage as well. That will connect you with an AWS bucket that you can use.

#### Personal Anecdote

Shared hosting can be tricky with Laravel. I would transition away as soon as I could. I use Laravel Forge to deploy servers and Digital Ocean or AWS for hosting.